# I want to show that $ \mid D pr(m) \mid \leq \dfrac{1}{1-\Vert pr(m)-m \Vert \Vert h_{pr(m)}\Vert}.$

Tags: differential-geometry

Let M be a smooth surface, and $U$ a neighborhood where the orthogonal projection pr is well defined.

I would like to show that  $ \forall m \in U$, if $ m \in S$, pr is differentiable on m and we have: $$ \mid D pr(m) \mid \leq \dfrac{1}{1-\Vert pr(m)-m \Vert \Vert h_{pr(m)}\Vert}.  $$  where $\Vert h_{pr(m)}\Vert$ denotes the norm of the second fundamental form. Here's what I tried so far: 
Let $ N_{pr(m)} $ the normal vector to S in pr(m). We put: $$  N_{pr(m)} = \epsilon \dfrac{pr(m)-m}{\parallel pr(m)-m \parallel} \ avec  \ \epsilon \in (-1,+1)  $$ 
We then have:  $$ pr(m)-m = <pr(m)-m, N_{pr(m)}> N_{pr(m)} .$$
Then, we obtain for all $ X \in T_{m}U$:

$$ Dpr(m)X = X+ < pr(m)-m, N_{pr(m)}>DN_{pr(m)}(Dpr(m)X)+ <Dpr(m)X-X,N_{pr(m)}>N_{pr(m)}+ <pr(m)-m,DN_{pr(m)}(Dpr(m)X)>N_{pr(m)}
$$
$$ = X+ \epsilon \parallel pr(m)-m \parallel DN_{pr(m)}(Dpr(m)X)-<X,N_{pr(m)}>N_{pr(m)} $$ 
Please how can I get that last equality? and is $ X - <X,N_{pr(m)}>N_{pr(m)}$ equal to the orthogonal projection of X onto the tangent space of S in $pr(m)$?
Please Help.